# Pass parameter from one servlet to another, which just received some other values also from a jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

How do i pass a parameter from a servlet to another servlet, which just recieved some other values also from a jsp...

I have a servlet which gets date, source and destination...after it goes to another jsp page, the user enters a bus ID and now i want this bus id as well as the date from the previous form to be got into another servlet

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways.

If you have a standard servlet container (like Apache Tomcat) then I'd go by passing parameters with a GET or POST call to the other servlet (i.e. with Apache Http client).

Below a GET call example using Apache HTTPClient 4

```
//create the HttpClient
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
//point the url to call
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/otherservlet?id=1&param2=hello");
//execute the call and consume the response
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// Get the response, if any
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
  (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  textView.append(line);
}
```

Otherwise I'd use JSM (java message service) if you can use a full-fledge application server.

Comment: The point isn't to send the request with the parameters, it's to have access to the previous sent parameters.

Comment: right! Sorry it was late and I haven't carefully read the question. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Servlet`s are in the same context and both requests happen within the same session, one after the other, the way to do this is to persist the parameter values you get in one `Servlet` so that they are available to the second `Servlet`.

```
String dateStr = request.getParameter("date"); // make sure to perform null checks
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("date", dateStr);
```

The parameter value is now stored in the `HttpSession` attributes. You can retrieve it from any other `Servlet` as long as you are still in the same `HttpSession`.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String dateStr = (String) session.getAttribute("date");
// you'll want to do null checks here too
// what if the requests were sent out of order?
```